# How to hide a parent element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML list

```
<button>Show/hide</button>

<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum<span class="green"> Some text</span></li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum<span class="green"> Some text</span></li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum<span class="green"> Some text</span></li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
```

and some jQuery code which toggles the `span`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".green").toggle();
    });
});
```

What I'd like to do now, is to toggle the entire `li` my `span` is nested in. Any idea how to this?

https://jsfiddle.net/vnprtra1/2/

Comment: `$(".green").parent().toggle();` see https://jsfiddle.net/vnprtra1/3/

Comment: You couldn't do a search for [hide parent jquery](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hide+parent+jquery&oq=hide+parent+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.760j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Rule number 1 of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Search and research

Comment: `$(".green").parent().closest('li').toggle();`

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".green").parent().toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: This works great, thanks!